# laravel ckfinder3 folder not appearing in

Tags: laravel, vue.js, ckfinder

For some reason I seem unable to add my folder to the list in the ckfinder file browser in an existing backend configuration. I have already tried a lot of things but all I can see it that it should appear based upon the ckfinder config? The folder exists and I have already checked the config numerous times.

There are no errors or logs anywhere...

just based on the default config here just omitted the non relevant parts (I think)
https://github.com/ckfinder/ckfinder-laravel-package/blob/master/src/config.php

ckfinder config:

```
/*=================================== Backends ========================================*/
$config['backends']['myfolder'] = [
    'name' => 'myfolder',
    'adapter' => 'local',
    'baseUrl' => config('app.url') . '/storage/myfolder/',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public/myfolder/'),
    'chmodFiles' => 0777,
    'chmodFolders' => 0755,
    'filesystemEncoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'followSymlinks' => true,
];

/*================================ Resource Types =====================================*/
$config['defaultResourceTypes'] = 'SomeFolder, OtherFolder, MyFolder';
$config['resourceTypes'] = [
    [
        'name' => 'MyFolder',
        'directory' => 'myfolder',
        'label' => 'MyFolder',
        'maxSize' => '8M',
        'allowedExtensions' => '7z,aiff,asf,avi,bmp,csv,doc,docx,fla,flv,gif,gz,gzip,ico,jpeg,jpg,mid,mov,mp3,mp4,mpc,mpeg,mpg,ods,odt,pdf,png,ppt,pptx,pxd,qt,ram,rar,rm,rmi,rmvb,rtf,sdc,sitd,svg,swf,sxc,sxw,tar,tgz,tif,tiff,txt,vsd,wav,wma,wmv,xls,xlsx,zip',
        'backend' => 'myfolder',
    ],
];

/*================================ Access Control =====================================*/
$config['roleSessionVar'] = 'ckfinder.user_role';
$config['accessControl'][] = [
    'role' => '*',//'role' => 'Admin',
    'resourceType' => 'MyFolder',
    'folder' => '/',

    'FOLDER_CREATE' => true,
    'FOLDER_RENAME' => true,
    'FOLDER_DELETE' => true,

    'FILE_UPLOAD' => true,
    'FILE_RENAME' => true,
    'FILE_DELETE' => true,

    'IMAGE_RESIZE' => true,
    'IMAGE_RESIZE_CUSTOM' => true,
];
```

some middleware for setting a user role:

```
class CkFinderUserRoleMiddleware
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): mixed
    {
        //some code omitted

        $_SESSION['ckfinder.user_role'] = //function that aquires admin value

        config()->set([           
            'ckfinder.backends.myfolder.baseUrl' => env('APP_URL') . storage_path('app/public/vrp'),
            'ckfinder.backends.myfolder.root' => storage_path('app/public/vrp'),
        ]);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

ck finder options in vue component:

```
let vm = this;

let CKFinderOptions = {
    chooseFiles: true,
    width: this.width,
    height: this.height,
    onInit: function (finder) {
        finder.on('files:choose', function (evt) {
            let file = evt.data.files.first();
            let url = file.getUrl();
            let protocol = url.indexOf('://') + 3;

            vm.loadAsset(url.substring(url.indexOf('/', protocol)));
        });

        finder.on('file:choose:resizedImage', function (evt) {
            let url = evt.data.resizedUrl.getUrl();
            let protocol = url.indexOf('://') + 3;

            vm.loadAsset(url.substring(url.indexOf('/', protocol)), true);
        });
    }
};

if (this.path) {
    CKFinderOptions.rememberLastFolder = false;
    CKFinderOptions.startupPath = `${this.resourceType}:${this.path}`;
}

CKFinder.popup(CKFinderOptions);
```